# vb.net TextBox submit not changing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I've got a legacy VB.Net app that I'm modifying in VS 2010; here's the relevant code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvCommentsEdit" runat="server" ShowHeader="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    *** On
                   <asp:Label ID="lblTimestamp" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("comment_date") %>'></asp:Label>
                   <asp:Label ID="lblUpdateBy" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("update_by") %>'></asp:Label> commented:<br />
                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditCommentPopup" runat="server" Columns="55" Rows="10" Text='<%# bind("text") %>' TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSaveComment" runat="server" OnClick="lnkSaveComment_Click">Save</asp:LinkButton>
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancelEdit" runat="server" OnClick="lnkCancelEdit_Click">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
                   <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCommentID" Value='<%# Bind("comment_id") %>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</form>
```

Code Behind is:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim IdNumber As Integer = sender.ClientQueryString
    Dim mydata As New Profile_Data

    gvCommentsEdit.DataSource = mydata.returnCommentsById(RequestedUsername, IdNumber)
    gvCommentsEdit.DataBind()

End Sub

Sub lnkSaveComment_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim myRow = sender.parent
    Dim mydata As New Profile_Data
    Dim IdNumber As String = CType(myRow.FindControl("hdnCommentID"), HiddenField).Value
    Dim text As String = CType(myRow.FindControl("txtEditCommentPopup"), TextBox).Text

    mydata.UpdateComment(IdNumber, text)

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "CloseWindowScript", "window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location;window.close();", True)
End Sub
```

End Class

This page is a popup from the main page and populates fine. The problem is when I change the txtEditCommentPopup TextBox, which then calls lnkSaveComment_Click(), it has the original textbox values, not the changed value. I'm not using AutoPostBack. Any ideas on why? Thanks!

Comment: Does the database get updated?  If so, set a breakpoint at gvCommentsEdit.DataBind(), and see if gvCommentsEdit.DataSource contains the new data you were expecting.

Comment: It updates the database, but it is the original value, so nothing changes; I just set a breakpoint at gvCommentsEdit.DataSource to confirm that it has the old value still there.

Comment: bind your grid on page load inside `If Not IsPostBack Then
        BindYourGridView()
    End If `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this in your page load

```
If Not IsPostBack Then 
     'your code 
  End If
```

so replace your `Page_Load` with this:-

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load    
    If Not IsPostBack Then

       Dim IdNumber As Integer = sender.ClientQueryString
       Dim mydata As New Profile_Data

       gvCommentsEdit.DataSource = mydata.returnCommentsById(RequestedUsername, IdNumber)
       gvCommentsEdit.DataBind()
  End If   
End Sub
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the database update is working correctly, the problem is that you are binding the GridView on every PostBack, but not *after* the data is updated.

When you click your button, you should see that your `Page_Load` method is called, your GridView is bound, then your `lnkSaveComment_Click` method is called, updating the database. But afterwards, you are not rebinding with the new data.

So my guess is that if you were to click the update button again (or cause another PostBack somehow), your new data would show up.

The fix would be to make sure you bind your GridView again after you update the data.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load    
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        BindGridView()
    End If    
End Sub

Sub lnkSaveComment_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim myRow = sender.parent
    Dim mydata As New Profile_Data
    Dim IdNumber As String = CType(myRow.FindControl("hdnCommentID"), HiddenField).Value
    Dim text As String = CType(myRow.FindControl("txtEditCommentPopup"), TextBox).Text

    mydata.UpdateComment(IdNumber, text)

    BindGridView()

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "CloseWindowScript", "window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location;window.close();", True)
End Sub

Sub BindGridView()
    Dim IdNumber As Integer = Page.ClientQueryString
    Dim mydata As New Profile_Data

    gvCommentsEdit.DataSource = mydata.returnCommentsById(RequestedUsername, IdNumber)
    gvCommentsEdit.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: You mean like doing a gvCommentsEdit.DataBind() as the first line in lnkSaveComment_Click? I tried that, but no change.

Comment: No, you need to do it _after_ you update your data. See my edit.

Comment: Hmm.. but lnkSaveComment_Click() gets called from the submit button (I.E., right after the edits), so the data has already changed by then, right? Not sure where else a DataBind() would make sense. Oh, there is a DataBind() in Page_Load, for what that's worth. Are you thinking of someplace else?

Comment: You are misunderstanding the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). My answer explains this. When you click the button, your `Page_Load` gets called first and rebinds your GridView with the __old__ data. Then your save handler gets called second, updates the database, but then does not rebind the GridView, leaving your GridView in an old state.

Comment: @box1763 before `button click` event `page_load` event occur first so it will bind new data each time as in your present code, thats why you are losing your data.